# Can I replace an unsigned apk with a signed apk in Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

I have an app in Google play that I built in Eclipse.
Recently I imported it to Android Studio, made some changes and I want to replace the apk file in the market.
In Eclipse I used unsigned apk and now it's signed one. 
Do you know if it can cause problems for the users?

EDIT:
When I try to upload it, this is what I get:

```
Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 07:F5:24:81:59:0B:28:48:A6:48:FC:E3:9B:D5:3D:06 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 79:B7:5D:76:80:32:22:E4:1B:33:5A:69:69:24:79:BA ]
```

Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The first APK you uploaded was most likely signed with a debug certificate as opposed to your release one. Google Play doesn't allow you to use a different certificate than the one you originally used, due to security issues. The whole idea behind the certificates is to prevent anyone from uploading potentially malicious code that claims it was by you, thus keeping you users a little safer. So, the only way to change your certificate is to unpublish your old app, create a new one in the console and re-upload. You will also have to change your app's package name to something else before you re-upload.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'll first try to open it again in Eclipse and make the changes again... I don't want to unpublish my app, I have users that I don't want to lose...

Comment: @Mor In the likely case you signed your first uploaded APK with your debug certificate, you probably won't be able to upload any updates soon because the debug certificate is usually configured to expire after 1 year. I fear there is no other way for you than to upload a properly signed version under a new package name and you'll probably have to assist your existing user base in migrating to the new app.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it... Is there a proper way to do it? I can't really contact each one...

Comment: @Mor Someone may have a better way, but if you still have access to the same debug certificate you could publish one last update using it. In that update, you could include a dialog that would give a bit of info and direct people to the new download page.

Comment: OK, I'll try to do it. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: So the solution was: Build->Generate Signed APK -> chose my old keystore(which was generated with Eclipse) and Google Play accepted the new apk.